# Spring 3.1 basic usage of Envirionment and PropertySource

Tags: spring, spring-environment

I want to inject property values into the Spring context when it is started.
I am trying to do this using the new Environment and PropertySource features of Spring 3.1.

In the class in which loads the Spring context, I define my own PropertySource class as follows:

```
private static class CustomPropertySource extends PropertySource<String> {
   public CustomPropertySource() {super("custom");}
      @Override
      public String getProperty(String name) {
      if (name.equals("region")) {
         return "LONDON";
      }
      return null;
}
```

Then, I add this property source to the application context:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext springIntegrationContext = 
   new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:META-INF/spring/ds-spring-intg-context.xml");
context.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addLast( new CustomPropertySource());
context.refresh();
context.start();
```

In one of my beans, I try to access the property value:

```
@Value("${region}")
public void setRegion(String v){
   ...
}
```

bur recieve the folowing error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  Could not resolve placeholder
>   'region' in string value [${region}]

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

when you pass an XML file location as a constructor argument to `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(..)` it straight away does the `context.refresh()/context.start()` methods.  so by passing in your XML locations, you're essentially doing it all in one pass and the context is already started/loaded by the time you get to call `context.getEnvironment().getPropertySources...`.

try this;

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext springIntegrationContext = 
   new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();
context.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addLast( new CustomPropertySource());
context.setLocations("classpath:META-INF/spring/ds-spring-intg-context.xml");
context.refresh();
```

it will set your sources, then your xml, *then* start the app context.